# Subscribe messages: errors at building the "topic tutorial" from the wiki

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I tried to get run an example of the [tutorial section of the wiki](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/beginner/topics): to subscribe and print out messages. I use this code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>    
#include "gazebo.hh"
#include "Transport.hh"
#include "Node.hh"
#include "subscribe.pb.h"
#include "msgs.h"
#include "world_stats.pb.h"
#include "MessageTypes.hh"

using namespace std;
using namespace gazebo;

void printMsg(Const WorldStatisticsPtr &_msg)
{
  std::cout << _msg->DebugString();
}

int main()
{
  gazebo::transport::init();
  gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new transport::Node());   
  node->Init();
  node->Subscribe("~/world_stats", &printMsg, this);
  return 0;
}
```

where I removed the last lines of the tutorial. During compiling, I got the following error(s):

```
   /test2_Gazebo/mainGazebo.cc:15:15: error: variable or field 'printMsg' declared void
   /test2_Gazebo/mainGazebo.cc:15:15: error: 'Const' was not declared in this scope
   /test2_Gazebo/mainGazebo.cc: In function 'int main()':
   /test2_Gazebo/mainGazebo.cc:25:37: error: 'printMsg' was not declared in this scope
   /test2_Gazebo/mainGazebo.cc:25:47: error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function
```

After searching for the error in the void function, I guess, that it has something to do with the argument, which could not be proper. Maybe I have to include some more header files? I tried to look around in the source files, but my poor attempts with "world_stats.pb.h", "msgs.h" and "MessageTypes.hh" haven't changed anything. The message system bases on google protobufs, is there a special knowledge about the handling necessary?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/119/subscribe-messages:-errors-at-building-the-%22topic-tutorial%22-from-the-wiki/) by [FerdinandT](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/44/ferdinandt/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There was a typo in the tutorial; thank you for catching it! There should be no space between Const and WorldStatisticsPtr, so line 15 should actually be:

void printMsg(ConstWorldStatisticsPtr &_msg)

Also, you can't use the 'this' keyword from a main function. I suggest you try integrating this code with one of the [example plugins](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/dd23b2695e3a8d8539b4f48ae35cad6801c775b8/examples/plugins/custom_messages?at=default).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0